# redux async example is not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am newbie in learning reactjs + redux
As the way in following the example of redux async, [redux async](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions), I found it works very well on the chrome and safari, but not firefox (latest, 60.0.1 (64it), OSX)

What the example does is using redux-thunk to grep data from reddit and show to UI, but network error is thrown when calling the fetch function

Here is the snippet (I modified it to get the fetch return object, but the logic is not changed),

```
// ${subreddit} = reactjs or front

const fetchPosts = subreddit => dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))
  let ret = fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
    .then(response => {
      return fetchReturn(response);
    })
    .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))
  return ret;
}
```

Here is the error message of the ret in browser,
[image shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNpFf.png)

It looks error happened when loading the middleware, but I've no clue how to fix it.
I thought this might due to the CORS and tried to put the file to localhost, but no luck.

Comment: From the network tab, the request to the reddit was not happen at all

Comment: I don't think you are having a CORS issue. Probably the call is being made with a wrong value (`subreddit` variable). Set a `.catch(err => console.log(err));` in the fetch request so you can have more info about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment hence I will leave it here.

There are different solutions shared in the [issue](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/301) that might be able to help you.

Otherwise, you can follow this [guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing) to add CORS support in your fetch method.

EDIT: Make sure you enabled the Promise polyfill using `babel-polyfill`